# Simple Question on Probability

Tags: probability

It is not a difficult problem,but it has puzzled me for a while.

How to prove:

$\left|\mu-m\right|
\le
\sigma$

where $\mu$ is the expectation,m is the median,${\sigma}^2$ is the variance.

THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: See "An inequality relating means and medians" in the following link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It holds, as $\def\E{\mathbb E}$$\E[m] = m$ if $X \in L^2(\mathbb P)$ with $\E[X] = \mu$, $E[(X-\mu)^2]= \sigma^2$, that
\begin{align*} \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}
  \E[\abs{\mu - m}] &= \E\bigl[\abs{\E[X-m]}\bigr]\\
  &\le \E\bigl[\E[\abs{X-m}]\bigr] &\text{as $\abs{\E[Y]} \le \E[\abs Y]$}\\
  &\le \E[\abs{X-\mu}] & \text{definition of the median}\\
  &= \E[1]^{1/2}\cdot \E[(X-m)^2]^{1/2} &\text{by Hölder}\\
  &=\sigma.
\end{align*}

Comment: I also get the answer today.Anyway ,thank you for your help.